# Compilation error in snprintf saying incompatible types

Tags: c, linux, wsl-2

I have this program with me. Where I am trying to concatenate a user input to a command, inorder to execute it in a wsl environment.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(){
    char cmd[100];
    char usr_in[50];

    fgets(usr_in, sizeof(usr_in), stdin);
    cmd = snprintf(cmd, sizeof(cmd), "ping %s", usr_in);

    system(cmd);
    return 0;
}
```

But this gives me the following error during compilation.

```
error: incompatible types in assignment of ‘int’ to ‘char [100]’
cmd = snprintf(cmd, sizeof(cmd), "ping %s", usr_in);
```

I am not able to figure out which integer assignment it is talking about. The **sizeof(cmd)** is the only integer there and it is a valid argument to the **snprintf**.

Comment: 1. You cannot assign to `cmd`. 2. `snprintf ` anyway returns an integer (not a char pointer/array).

Comment: @wohlstad I missed the return part. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`snprintf` returns `int` (the number of characters printed) and you are trying to assign the return value to `cmd` which is `char[100]`.

Comment: Thank you so much. Can't believe I was overlooking this.

Answer (score 2):

`snprintf` returns an `int`. `cmd = snprintf…` attempts to assign that `int` to the array `cmd`.

Comment: Can't believe I overlooked this. Thank you.